# SPFx, Fabric, and Modern Themes - Where are they available?

Tags: spfx, theme, modern-experience, fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

According to the last few comments of this [techcommunity post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/New-site-theming-options-for-SharePoint-sites-in-Office-365/ba-p/94001/page/2#comments), modern themes are currently only available on the 2 modern group-connected team and communication site templates.  Does that mean absorbing contextual themes for SharePoint customization's such as SPFx web parts and Fabric components (like described below), will only work when they are housed in those specific site templates?

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-theme-colors-in-your-customizations
2. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/colors